# Simple Java PriorityQueue<String> error

Tags: java, priority-queue

All I am doing is add three strings to a Java PriorityQueue and then print them out
This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        PriorityQueue<String> pq=new PriorityQueue<String>();
        pq.add("abc");
        pq.add("ability");
        pq.add("aberdeen");

        String s="ability";
        System.out.println(s.compareTo("aberdeen"));

        System.out.println(pq);
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

```
4
[abc, ability, aberdeen]
```

Shouldn't this be `abc, aberdeen, ability` instead. since that's the correct alphabetic order?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the documentation of [`PriorityQueue.iterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#iterator%28%29):

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this queue. The iterator does not return the elements in any particular order.

That's what `toString()` is using to construct the string representation, as the implementation is [inherited from `AbstractCollection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29):

> Returns a string representation of this collection. The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). [...]

Try dequeuing the results instead, and you'll get the expected order:

```
while (pq.size() > 0) {
    System.out.println(pq.poll());
}
```

Output:

```
abc
aberdeen
ability
```

Comment: @SJuan76: Well, it uses lexicographical order, which for two ASCII-only, lower-case values is the same... and the OP's sample code explicitly shows the results of `compareTo` for `aberdeen` and `ability`.

Comment: My bad, I had the idea that somehow the first check was the length of the String. Rereading the javadoc, I was wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The queue works properly. Run this code:

```
PriorityQueue<String> pq=new PriorityQueue<String>();
pq.add("abc");
pq.add("ability");
pq.add("aberdeen");
System.out.println(pq);
for (String s; (s = pq.poll()) != null;) System.out.println(s);
```

It will print

```
[abc, ability, aberdeen]
abc
aberdeen
ability
```

The reason lies with the fact that the priority semantics apply only to the dequeue operation, whereas in other respects the queue is bound only by the contract of the plain `java.util.Collection`: its iterator is not required to observe any particular order, and specifically, `PriorityQueue`'s iterator happens to observe the insertion order.